# Case Overview Button Not working

Tags: civicase, search, error

I'm using Civi CRM as a local Healthwatch.
I can't see an overview of cases - when I click the button, or try to enact a search, the page below shows. 
Any idea how to fix it?

TIA!

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide any more information - e.g. the version of CiviCRM and the version of the CMS you are using (WordPress/Joomla/Drupal)?

Comment: Are you able to access other pages in CiviCRM?

Comment: and pls spell out what you have done by way of setting up Case, or whether you are trying to just use the inbuilt stuff. currently it is like you have told the doctor you don't feel well ;-) hopefully no doctor would prescribe on that level of info

Answer (score 1):

Check the civi log for more details. It looks like you're using drupal so it's either under sites/warrington.healthwatchcrm.co.uk/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog or sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog.